# What is "Assistant 1.0" app and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: uninstallation, system-apps

I have MetroPCS and a ZTE ZMAX Z970 phone with Android 4.4.4

This app appeared, I don't know exactly when, and it's got some worrisome permissions and I want it off my phone, but it has no uninstall option and there's nothing on Google Web Search about it.

It looks goofy enough to be malware.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Assistant 1.0]
[image: IMG: Permissions]

Comment: Is the device rooted? If not, then you can't install that app easily. If your device has never been rooted then assume that your OEM has shipped that app in the device. Also, give us its package name. Install [tag:adb] and give us the output of `pm list packages -f -s | grep "Assistant"`.

Comment: ZTE ships with a smartphone management tool name Mi-assistant. Could this be that? Google ID: `com.zte.heartyservice`

Comment: Keep in mind that uninstalling this app could eliminate some core feature of your device.

Comment: @DanHenderson, thanks for the warning. I would have to root it to uninstall it, and I don't think this phone can be rooted.

Comment: @Firelord, it's not rooted. I don't think this model can be. I'll run pm list packages and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @Manubhargav, I don't think so. The icon is not the same and my app can't be ran or interacted with. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zte.heartyservice

Comment: Giving the package name would help as @Firelord suggested. Also if you're not comfortable with adb,  you can install [System Info for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi&hl=en) and see package name.

Comment: @Manubhargav, thank you I will install that. Signal too bad at the moment, but I'll check it when the icon hits my android desktop.